# Start jenkins job immediately after creation by seed job, with parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

[Start jenkins job immediately after creation by seed job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268485/start-jenkins-job-immediately-after-creation-by-seed-job)

I can start a job from within the job dsl like this:

```
queue('my-job')
```

But how do I start a job with argument or parameters? I want to pass that job some arguments somehow.

Comment: Hi, I think your question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659175/jenkins-jobdsl-queue-with-parameters). Cheers.

Comment: Are you using jenkins declarative pipelines?

Comment: @lvthillo this is not using pipelines, it is using the Jenkins Job DSL.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, you can't.

But what you can do is creating it from a pipeline (jobDsl step), then run it. Something more or less like...

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('jobs creation') {
      steps {
        jobDsl targets: 'my_job.dsl',
               additionalParameters: [REQUESTED_JOB_NAME: "my_job's_name"]

        build job: "my_job's_name",
              parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'DRY_RUN', value: true)]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With a barebones 'my_job.dsl'...

```
pipelineJob(REQUESTED_JOB_NAME) {
  definition {
    // blah...
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** As you see, I explicitly set the name of the job from the calling pipeline (the REQUESTED_JOB_NAME var) because otherwise I don't know how to make the jobDSL code to return the name of the job it creates back to the calling pipeline.

I use this "trick" to avoid the *"job params go one run behind"* problem.  I use the DRY_RUN param of the job (I use a hidden param, in fact) to run a *"do-nothing"* build as its name implies, so by the time others need to use the job for *"real stuff"* its params section has already been properly parsed.